# What does count() method of nltk.corpus.reader.wordnet.Lemma return?

Tags: python, nltk, wordnet, lemmatization

Here is my code:

```
from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn

eat = wn.lemma('eat.v.03.eat')
print(eat.count())
print(help(eat.count))
```

The output should be like this:

```
4
Help on method count in module nltk.corpus.reader.wordnet:

count() method of nltk.corpus.reader.wordnet.Lemma instance
    Return the frequency count for this Lemma

None
```

What does the '4' means? Are there 4 entries counted in the dictionary for the lemma 'eat.v.03.eat'? How can I get these four entries? Thank you, guys.

I have tried to read the document and the source code, the link is here:
https://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.corpus.reader.wordnet.html

Here is the source code:

```
    def lemma_count(self, lemma):
        """Return the frequency count for this Lemma"""
        # Currently, count is only work for English
        if lemma._lang != "eng":
            return 0
        # open the count file if we haven't already
        if self._key_count_file is None:
            self._key_count_file = self.open("cntlist.rev")
        # find the key in the counts file and return the count
        line = _binary_search_file(self._key_count_file, lemma._key)
        if line:
            return int(line.rsplit(" ", 1)[-1])
        else:
            return 0
```

It seems to search and count keys in a key_count file. What is this method counting? What are the values of these keys?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

According to the wordnet document, each line in cntlist.rev file is of the form:

```
sense_key  sense_number  tag_cnt
```

So the 4 here returned by the count method is tag_cnt.

Here is the document link: https://wordnet.princeton.edu/documentation/cntlist5wn

- A sense (or word sense) is a discrete representation of one aspect of the meaning of a word.
- `sense_number` is a decimal integer indicating the sense number of the word, within the part of speech encoded in `sense_key`, in the WordNet database.
- `tag_cnt` represents the decimal number of times the sense is tagged in various semantic concordance texts. A `tag_cnt` of 0 indicates that the sense has not been semantically tagged.